# How do I set the background color of a number based on whether it goes up or down?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to catch a state change for a number. I've got a component that renders a number. When the value changes, I want to set the background to be green or red, depending on whether it moved up or down.

I'm actually not sure this is possible to do in functional component. Am I missing something?

Here's my latest (failed) attempt.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const FlashNumber = ({ value }) => {
  const [prevValue, setPrevValue] = useState(null)
  const [bgColor, setBgColor] = useState('white')

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (prevValue !== null) {
      if (value > prevValue) {
        setBgColor('green')
        setTimeout(() => {
          setBgColor('white')
        }, 1000)
      } else if (value < prevValue) {
        setBgColor('red')
        setTimeout(() => {
          setBgColor('white')
        }, 1000)
      }
    }
    setPrevValue(value)
  }, [value, prevValue])

  return <div style={{ backgroundColor: bgColor }}>{value}</div>
}

export default FlashNumber
```

Comment: Why setTimeout? That's a red flag in an effect. Effects run after render. State changes cause renders.

Comment: Well I hoped to clear it after 1 second. I guess I don't have to, I can clear it with a CSS animation too.

Comment: Clear a timeout like this https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#putting-it-all-together

Comment: The thing is, your timeout is setting state so then it will cause another render  =)

Comment: So I removed that bit as it wasn't relevant, but it looks like the issue is that the 'useState' gets reset after every render, so the background never ends up changing.

Comment: Your example takes a value as prop but I don't see it set previous value. Is this piece missing? Wait, no, I'm blind.

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is the issue? [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-dream-inkw4u?file=/src/App.js). The only thing that needs some fixes is the setTimeout, so it will not flicker if value is modified too fast.

Comment: Yeah I see the same as @SergeySosunov - I just popped this into a sandbox and i see it flash green

Comment: Could you link to the sandbox?

Comment: here's mine https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-maxwell-d6mlir?file=/src/App.js - ah, and it does it one time.

Comment: @Nikki9696 is it saved? I see an empty file at FlashNumber.js

Comment: Right yep; it gets stuck. The issue is separating out the state updates. That's where I'm stuck. It's broken in a subtle sort of way.

Comment: As I look at this, I see that I don't think you need an effect at all. Gimme a few, I'm pretty sure Memo will do.

Comment: Sergey answered it as asked, but if you want to see it without any need for an effect, the sandbox should be good now. https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-maxwell-d6mlir?file=/src/FlashNumber.js

Comment: @Nikki9696 Im affraid it still flickering in your sandbox, press + 2 times and - 2 times pretty fast - color will freeze to green when increased, then it will still be green when decreased and then either it will become white, either red, depending on how fast you clicked

Comment: @SergeySosunov - ok well it was worth a shot  =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably try to do most of the work in a css animation and keep the timeout hassle out of the component.

```
import classnames from "clsx"; // you can replace this with a bit of ternary gymnastics

const FlashNumber = ({ value }) => {
  const prevValue = usePrevious(value);
  return (
    <div className={classnames(
      value > prevValue && 'increasing',
      value < prevValue && 'decreasing',
    )}>
      {value}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
const usePrevious = (value) => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => { ref.current = value; }, [value]);
  return ref.current;
}
```

```css
@keyframes flash-red {
  0%   { background-color: red; }
  100% { background-color: white; }
}

@keyframes flash-green {
  0%   { background-color: green; }
  100% { background-color: white; }
}

.increasing {
  animation: flash-green 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.decreasing {
  animation: flash-red 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Note: this flashes only when the direction is changed. If you want to flash whenever a click happens look into the following section:

```
const FlashNumber = ({ value }) => {
  const prevValue = usePrevious(value);
  const changed = useAlternating(value, ['flip', 'flop']);

  return (
    <div className={classnames(
      value > prevValue && 'increasing',
      value < prevValue && 'decreasing',
      changed,
    )}>
      {value}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
const useAlternating = (trigger, range) => {
  const [prev, setPrev] = useState(trigger);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  if (trigger !== prev) {
    setPrev(trigger);
    setIndex(i => (i + 1) % range.length);
  }
  return range[index];
}
```

```css
@keyframes flash-flip {
  0%   { background-color: var(--color); }
  100% { background-color: white; }
}

@keyframes flash-flop {
  0%   { background-color: var(--color); }
  100% { background-color: white; }
}

.increasing { --color: green; }

.decreasing { --color: red; }

.flip {
  animation: flash-flip 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.flop {
  animation: flash-flop 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` can return a cleanup function, in that way you will be able to stop "previously set" timeout callbacks from execution.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-dream-inkw4u?file=/src/App.js

```js
const { useMemo, useState, useRef, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setVal((x) => x + 1)}>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => setVal((x) => x - 1)}>-</button>
      <FlashNumber value={val} />
    </div>
  );
}

const FlashNumber = ({ value }) => {
  const prevValueRef = useRef(value);
  const [bgColor, setBgColor] = useState("white");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (value > prevValueRef.current) {
      setBgColor("green");
    } else if (value < prevValueRef.current) {
      setBgColor("red");
    }
    prevValueRef.current = value;
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setBgColor("white");
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [value]);

  return <div style={{ backgroundColor: bgColor }}>{value}</div>;
};

// v18.x+
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```